# How to programmatically access the d: DesignHeight and d: DesignWidth?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to programmatically access the d: DesignHeight and d: DesignWidth?
With C#

> ```
> <UsеrControl x:Class="MySpace.MyControl"
>          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
>          mc:Ignorable="d" 
>          d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="360">
> ```

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd need to do this?

Comment: I want to get the original Apect Ratio for the item.
Since after the new operator width and length = NaN (Auto)
MyControl ctrl = new MyControl ()
// ctrl.Width == NaN

Comment: You want to use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`

Comment: @Mixer new operator??? **Don't Create or Manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.**. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ActualWidth is equal to zero.
If the check immediately after the constructor

Comment: @Mixer please read my comment again. You're not supposed to mess with the UI in procedural code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create dynamically some UserControls

Comment: @Mixer You should use a `ContentPresenter` and some `DataTemplates`, not procedural code. Please post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
    MyControl ctrl=new MyControl();
    ctrl.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    //ctrl.DesiredSize.Width==design width
    //ctrl.DesiredSize.Height==design height
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't "access" that programatically.

the [Documentation for the `mc:Ignorable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states:

> Specifies which XML namespace prefixes encountered in a markup file
>   may be ignored by a XAML processor

Which means that XML attributes and elements inside the namespaces indicated by this attribute will be ignored by the XAML compiler, and thus not accessible at runtime.

Additionally, there is no need to mess with the UI in procedural code in XAML based technologies. You're on the wrong track.

**Don't Create or Manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.**

Provide additional information about what you're trying to do here if you need a more detailed answer.